# Matlab: Three short questions regarding caption and drawing

Tags: matlab

I have three questions. I hope you can help me.

First question:
I have one input point (x/y) from this point i want to draw a rectangular.
The corner points are always the coordinate axis.

Second question:
I have one y-value. I want to draw a horizontal line from x=0 -> x= diagramm end

Third question:
I want to do a caption in my diagramm. Related on a certain coordiante point.

I hope you understand my questions. My english is not the best.

Thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqVKg.png)

Comment: its not a homework ok? this are just part questions regarding formatting my data plot... sorry!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Question:
   you can add a rectangle with the command `rectangle('Position', [0 0 x y])` to the active figure. The input is actually `[x0 y0 width height]` where `x0` and `y0` are the coordinates of the left bottom corner of the rectangle.

   2. Question:
      I don't know a way to automatically plot a line to the diagram end. But a workaround could be to simply plot a horizontal line with the command `line([xmin xmax], [y y])` to the active figure. But you have to specify the `xmin = 0` and `xmax` (bigger than the axis). Does that work for you?
   3. Questions: you can add e.g. text to a specific location with the command `text( x,y,'String')`.

Another way for Questions 1 and 3 is to use annotations.

Does that help you?

Regards,
Michael